# Angular JS ng-if an ng-repeat complex match length is greater than given value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have an ng-repeat that shows a table based on one loop, and then a cell based on a different loop:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="r in roles | limitTo: 30">
     <td>{{r.name}}</td>
     <td>
        <span ng-repeat="t in users100 | limitTo: r.userLimit" ng-if="t.role == r.name"><a href="{{t.id}}">{{t.full_name}}</a></span> 
        <span ng-if="true"><a href="" ng-click="r.userLimit=500">Show all</a></span>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Each row is a Role, first cell shows the role's name.

Second cell shows all results from a different dataset where the `role` in that set matches the original set's `role` value. (It repeats a `SPAN` for each match up to `r.userLimit`, set in the JSON at 20)

The A tag has a click which sets the value of `r.userLimit` to 500, so it shows all the users.

My question is, I only want to show this link IF the number of matches to the initial repeater is greater than the value of r.userLimit (20)

So I thought

```
ng-if="((t.role == r.name).length > r.userLimit)"
```

But my syntax is wrong, since the link never shows.  What's wrong wih my syntax?

Comment: `(t.role == r.name).length` will never work, as you are trying to get length of boolean.. boolean doesn't support length property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to get 2 lengths: the original array and the filtered one:

This is how you can do so with `ng-repeat`:

```
<span ng-repeat="t in shownUsers = (users100 | limitTo: limit)">
```

Or, even easier, with Angular 1.3:

```
<span ng-repeat="t in users100 | limitTo: limit as shownUsers">
```

Then, you use the two with `ng-if` for "show all". You also don't need to hack "all" with "a very high number":

```
<span ng-show="shownUsers.length < users100.length" ng-click="limit = users100.length">
   Show All
</span>
```

**As a bonus**, this can also enable you to do "show more" quite easily:

```
<span ng-show="shownUsers.length < users100.length" ng-click="limit = limit + 10">
   show more
</span>
```

**EDIT:** There is further complexity if the results are themselves filtered, then the `as alias` would not suffice. In this case, the following works (shortening variable names for readability):

```
<span ng-repeat="t in shown = (filtered = (users | filter: {role: r.name}) | limitTo: limit)">
```

and then, use `shown.length` against `filtered.length`:

```
<span ng-show="shown.length < filtered.length" ng-click="limit = users.length">
   show all
</span>
```

Comment: Where does "shownUsers" come from?  That has me a little confused.  BTW I am using 1.3.

Comment: @Steve, `shownUsers` is an alias for the array filtered with `limitTo` assigned within the `ng-repeat` expression. Actually, with an array further filtered (on `r.name`), there is a bit more complexity - I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: I get no results at all with `<span ng-repeat="t in shown = (filtered = (users100 | filter: {t.role: r.name}) | limitTo: r.userLimit)">{{t.full_name}}</span>`

Comment: @Steve, it should be `filter: {role: r.name}`

Comment: @Steve, just reset the `r.userLimit` - I don't understand what the problem is. Here's an example - let me know if something is not clear: http://plnkr.co/edit/nXLHz0qjqMsl14GY0WBJ?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I actually deleted that comment.  I caught my silly error immediately.  Works fine.  My apologies.